# Limit on number of Express Application MIddleware?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

We use an express backend and we recently ran into a strange bug when adding a new middleware to one of our routes. We have been binding the handlers to the route as follows:

```
app.all('/route', [AsyncFunction1, AsyncFunction2, AsyncFunction3, AsyncFunction4, AsyncFunction5])
```

I added another Middleware to the route, so now we have:

```
app.all('/route', [AsyncFunction1, AsyncFunction2, AsyncFunction3, AsyncFunction4, AsyncFunction5, AsyncFunction6])
```

It worked fine and as expected until we run the containerized version of it (we run containerized versions for production). Suddenly, anything but GET requests dont' work on that route. Hitting it with an OPTIONS request returns "GET, HEAD". Again, it works fine locally.

We tried completely commenting out the new middleware and just have it return `next()`, but it doesn't work. We've tried removing one of the other, existing middleware, and the endpoint works again. We tried duplicating one of the other, existing middleware with a new name and adding it in place of the new one we made, and we get the same error. We've tried numerous different things, and it seems that the **number** of middleware is the limiting factor. Everything I've read makes no mention of there being a limit. Even more strangely, it works locally but not when containerized??

We did come up with two fixes. One was to assign the handlers as follows:

```
app.all('/route', AsyncFunction1)
app.all('/route', AsyncFunction2)
app.all('/route', AsyncFunction3)
.... so on for all 6
```

This works as expected but is a very low-level change of the sort we'd like to avoid if possible. We ended up moving the logic of the new middleware into one of the existing middlewares. Everything works as expected.

But there's something weird going on here and we don't know what!

The container image uses the same version of node and npm we are running locally. I'm thinking it might be some sort of resource constraint? I don't really know.

Is there any type of limit on the number of handlers added via array?

Comment: Did you check how many ,middleware handlers were executed in the chain successfully and how many of them did you indicate?

Comment: Great question - none of the middleware handlers execute for a POST request, but all execute for a GET request.

Comment: So if you remove `any` handler in the chain - all remaining handlers start working?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Does it mean that you can create a reproducible minimal example of the service and Docker file so any person can get the same results?

Comment: And if so then the next step would be to create an issue in express.js repo